# Dialogflow Webhook Format vs. Conversation Webhook Format

Tags: webhooks, dialogflow-es, actions-on-google, google-assistant-sdk

There are two types of fulfilments provides by Google Actions - Dialogflow Webhook Format & Conversation Webhook Format. In my understanding (as per this doc- https://developers.google.com/actions/build/json/conversation-webhook-json) Google sends "Conversation Webhook Format" request if we are using Actions SDK and Google uses "Dialogflow Webhook Format" if we use DialogFlow. Is this understanding correct?

The reason I am asking this is because the request format from Google has suddenly changed from the last two days from Dialogflow Webhook Format to Conversation Webhook Format. We are not using Actions SDK, so to me it appears some bug from Google. Is this change possible using settings?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your question about the message format sounds correct.

Some of the confusion, however, is that if you're using the Actions on Google Simulator - you will always see the "Conversation Format" version. This is because AoG sends this to Dialogflow, which then converts it into the "Dialogflow Format" before it sends it to your webhook. (It does a similar conversion on the way back.) So if you're just looking at things through the Simulator, you may get confused about what you will actually see.

Also keep in mind that the "Conversation Format" is also (mostly) sent along *inside* the "Dialogflow Format" under `originalDetectIntentRequest.payload`. If you're not looking carefully, you'll see it there and may miss the other parts of the message format that are intended for Dialogflow.

If you are actually seeing the Conversation Format JSON in your Dialogflow webhook - this is extremely strange. There is no setting that you can control that should be able to do this. You should contact Google through the [Support page](https://developers.google.com/actions/support/) to try and clarify what is going on.

Comment: Thanks @Prisoner. It helped. I recently applied a new SSL certificate and due to that Google was not able to hit my server. Though when I was using Google Actions Simulator, request was going through and it was using "Conversation Format". My code was failing due to that. I fixed the SSL certificate issue and my app started working again.
Interestingly, when I was using Simulator, I was receiving "Conversation Format" requests on my server api-endpoint as well which complicated my troubleshooting process.